# How to get sum of a column at last page of active reports

Tags: activereports

I have a active report that has two column named Deposit and Withdrawal.I want to get sum of both the columns at last page of active report. I have done some code in ReportStart event

```
var fldDepositTotal = ar.Sections["gfDetail"].Controls["fldDepositTotal"] as DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox;
var fldWithdrawalTotal = ar.Sections["gfDetail"].Controls["fldWithdrawalTotal"] as DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox;

            fldDepositTotal.DataField = "AmountD"; // Your datafield value
            fldDepositTotal.SummaryFunc = SummaryFunc.Sum;
            fldDepositTotal.SummaryGroup = "ghDetail";
            fldDepositTotal.SummaryRunning = SummaryRunning.Group;
            fldDepositTotal.SummaryType = SummaryType.GrandTotal;


            fldWithdrawalTotal.DataField = "AmountW"; // Your datafield value
            fldWithdrawalTotal.SummaryFunc = SummaryFunc.Sum;
            fldWithdrawalTotal.SummaryGroup = "ghDetail";
            fldWithdrawalTotal.SummaryRunning = SummaryRunning.Group;
            fldWithdrawalTotal.SummaryType = SummaryType.GrandTotal;
```

I have make it in report footer also but still not getting sum of Deposit and Withdrawal amount. How can I get sum of columns?

Answer (score 1):

The [SummaryRunning setting](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.SummaryRunning.html) basically defines when to *reset the accumulating total back to zero*. In the case of a grand total value at the report level you don't want the value to be reset - you want it to continue accumulating throughout the entire report. So you don't need the `SummaryGroup` and `SummaryRunning` properties here. So based on the sample in [the SummaryType property's documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox~SummaryType.html) you can set the SummaryGroup and SummaryRunning properties as follows:

```
 fldDepositTotal.DataField = "AmountD";
 fldDepositTotal.SummaryFunc = SummaryFunc.Sum;
 fldDepositTotal.SummaryGroup = null;
 fldDepositTotal.SummaryRunning = SummaryRunning.None;
 fldDepositTotal.SummaryType = SummaryType.GrandTotal;
```